# Sections and tabs DRY - WordPress settings API

Tags: functions, wp-admin, settings-api

I have made a custom setting page containing 3 settings sections under 3 tabs. However I am a total noob when it comes to PHP and I feel like I have written a lot of unnecessary, repeated code. My setting fields are exactly the same under different tabs, but I could not find another way to save them separately in the database.
Is there a way to shorten the code with an array for example? How could I reuse the same setting field in separate tab?

I'll be grateful for some tutoring.

Here's the code from my functions.php:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'myTheme_admin');

    function myTheme_admin() {
        /* Base Menu */
        add_menu_page(
        'myTheme settings',  // Admin page title
        'myTheme settings',  // Admin menu label
        'manage_options',
        'myTheme-general-options', // Admin slug
        'myTheme_general_index'); // Display Page
    }

    add_action('admin_init', 'myTheme_options');
    function myTheme_options() { 

    /* First Box Options Section */

    add_settings_section( 
        'myTheme_first_box', // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
        'First box settings',
        'boxes_front_page_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section
        'first_box_option' // Page on which to add this section of options
    );


    add_settings_field(  
        'box_first_title',         // ID used to identify the field throughout the theme             
        'Title',                    // The label to the left of the option interface element
        'box_first_input_callback',   
        'first_box_option',         // The page on which this option will be added            
        'myTheme_first_box',          // ID of the section
        array(
            'box_first_title' 
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_first_description',                      
        'Description',               
        'box_first_desc_callback',   
        'first_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_first_box',
        array(
            'box_first_description' 
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_first_link',                      
        'Link',               
        'box_first_input_callback',   
        'first_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_first_box',
        array(
            'box_first_link' 
        ) 
    );

    /*------------------------------

         Second Box Options Section 

    --------------------------------
    */

    add_settings_section( 
        'myTheme_second_box',
        'Ustawienia boksu drugiego',
        'boxes_front_page_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section
        'second_box_option'
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_second_title',                      
        'Title',               
        'box_second_input_callback',   
        'second_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_second_box',
        array(
            'box_second_title' 
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_second_description',                      
        'Description',               
        'box_second_desc_callback',   
        'second_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_second_box',
        array(
            'box_second_description' 
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_second_link',                      
        'Link',               
        'box_second_input_callback',   
        'second_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_second_box',
        array(
            'box_second_link' 
        ) 
    );


    /*------------------------------

         Third Box Options Section 

    --------------------------------
    */

    add_settings_section( 
        'myTheme_third_box',
        'Ustawienia boksu trzeciego',
        'boxes_front_page_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section
        'third_box_option'
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_third_title',                      
        'Title',               
        'box_third_input_callback',   
        'third_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_third_box',
        array(
            'box_third_title' 
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_third_description',                      
        'Description',               
        'box_third_desc_callback',   
        'third_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_third_box',
        array(
            'box_third_description' 
        ) 
    );

    add_settings_field(  
        'box_third_link',                      
        'Link',               
        'box_third_input_callback',   
        'third_box_option',                     
        'myTheme_third_box',
        array(
            'box_third_link' 
        ) 
    );


    register_setting('first_box_option', 'first_box_option');
    register_setting('second_box_option', 'second_box_option');
    register_setting('third_box_option', 'third_box_option');

}

/* Call Backs
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function boxes_front_page_callback() { 
        echo '<p>Lorem ipsum</p>'; 
    }

    function box_first_input_callback($args) { 

        $options = get_option('first_box_option'); 

        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" id="'  . $args[0] . '" name="first_box_option['  . $args[0] . ']" value="' . $options[''  . $args[0] . ''] . '"></input>';

    }

    function box_second_input_callback($args) { 

        $options = get_option('second_box_option'); 

        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" id="'  . $args[0] . '" name="second_box_option['  . $args[0] . ']" value="' . $options[''  . $args[0] . ''] . '"></input>';

    }

    function box_third_input_callback($args) { 

        $options = get_option('third_box_option'); 

        echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" id="'  . $args[0] . '" name="third_box_option['  . $args[0] . ']" value="' . $options[''  . $args[0] . ''] . '"></input>';

    }

    function box_first_desc_callback($args) { 

        $options = get_option('first_box_option'); 

        echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="50" class="large-text" id="'  . $args[0] . '" name="first_box_option['  . $args[0] . ']">' . $options[''  . $args[0] . ''] . '</textarea>';

    }

    function box_second_desc_callback($args) { 

        $options = get_option('second_box_option'); 

        echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="50" class="large-text" id="'  . $args[0] . '" name="second_box_option['  . $args[0] . ']">' . $options[''  . $args[0] . ''] . '</textarea>';

    }

    function box_third_desc_callback($args) { 

        $options = get_option('third_box_option'); 

        echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="50" class="large-text" id="'  . $args[0] . '" name="third_box_option['  . $args[0] . ']">' . $options[''  . $args[0] . ''] . '</textarea>';

    }


/* Display Page
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
function myTheme_general_index() {
?>
    <div class="wrap">  
        <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>  
        <h2>myTheme Settings</h2>  
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>  

        <?php  
                $active_tab = isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'tab' ] : 'boks_pierwszy';  
        ?>  

        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">  
            <a href="?page=myTheme-general-options&tab=boks_pierwszy" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'boks_pierwszy' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Boks pierwszy</a>  
            <a href="?page=myTheme-general-options&tab=boks_drugi" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'boks_drugi' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Boks drugi</a>
            <a href="?page=myTheme-general-options&tab=boks_trzeci" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'boks_trzeci' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>">Boks trzeci</a>
        </h2>  


        <form method="post" action="options.php">  

            <?php 
            if( $active_tab == 'boks_pierwszy' ) {  
                settings_fields( 'first_box_option' );
                do_settings_sections( 'first_box_option' ); 
            } else if( $active_tab == 'boks_drugi' ) {
                settings_fields( 'second_box_option' );
                do_settings_sections( 'second_box_option' );
            } else if( $active_tab == 'boks_trzeci' ) {
                settings_fields( 'third_box_option' );
                do_settings_sections( 'third_box_option' );
            } 
            ?>             
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form> 

    </div> 
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could do something like this: 
Create an associative array for settings, then loop through them to create settings and sections for each field.

```
$settings = array(
    'setting_1_id' => array(
        'title'=>'First Box Settings',
        'page'=>'first_box_option',
        'fields'=> array(
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_first_title',
                'title'=>'Title',
                'callback'=> 'text_callback'
                ),
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_first_desc',
                'title'=>'Description',
                'callback'=> 'textarea_callback'
                ),
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_first_link',
                'title'=>'Link',
                'callback'=> 'text_callback'
                ),

            )
        ),
    'setting_2_id' => array(
        'title'=>'Second Box Settings',
        'page'=>'second_box_option',
        'fields'=> array(
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_second_title',
                'title'=>'Title',
                'callback'=> 'text_callback'
                ),
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_second_desc',
                'title'=>'Description',
                'callback'=> 'textarea_callback'
                ),
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_second_link',
                'title'=>'Link',
                'callback'=> 'text_callback'
                ),

            )
        ),
    'setting_3_id' => array(
        'title'=>'Third Box Settings',
        'page'=>'third_box_option',
        'fields'=> array(
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_third_title',
                'title'=>'Title',
                'callback'=> 'text_callback'
                ),
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_third_desc',
                'title'=>'Description',
                'callback'=> 'textarea_callback'
                ),
            array(
                'id'=> 'box_third_link',
                'title'=>'Link',
                'callback'=> 'text_callback'
                ),

            )
        ),

);
```

Then you can use the foreach to loop through each settings.

```
foreach( $settings as $id => $values){
    add_settings_section( 
        $id, // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
        $values['title'],
        'boxes_front_page_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section
        $values['page'] // Page on which to add this section of options
    );

    // Loop through the fields to add different fields
    foreach ($values['fields'] as $field) {
        add_settings_field(  
            $field['id'],         // ID used to identify the field throughout the theme             
            $field['title'],                    // The label to the left of the option interface element
            $field['callback'],   
            $values['page'],         // The page on which this option will be added            
            $id,          // ID of the section
            array(
                $values['page'],        //option name
                $field['title']     //id 
            ) 
        );
    }

    register_setting($values['page'], $values['page']);

}
```

And finally you only need three callbacks, for text, textarea, and frontpage

```
/* 
 Call Backs
 */
function boxes_front_page_callback() { 
    echo '<p>Lorem ipsum</p>'; 
}

function text_callback($args) { 

    $options = get_option($args[0]); 

    echo '<input type="text" class="regular-text" id="'  . $args[1] . '" name="'. $args[0] .'['  . $args[1] . ']" value="' . $options[''  . $args[1] . ''] . '"></input>';

}


function textarea_callback($args) { 

    $options = get_option($args[0]); 

    echo '<textarea rows="8" cols="50" class="large-text" id="'  . $args[1] . '" name="'. $args[0] .'['  . $args[1] . ']">' . $options[''  . $args[1] . ''] . '</textarea>';

}
```

I have already tested this, works as intended. 
Click [here](https://gist.github.com/digvijayad/946e60b8c8c3a7984800608143e625f0) to look at the gist of the full code

Comment: Thank you, Digvijayad. It looks and reads a lot better now, although I still need some time to get used to nested arrays. It mos def works. It says here I should not thank you, but I really appreciate your effort of improving such a long code.